# Java library to generate DDL

Tags: java

Are there any Java libraries that allow me to generate DDL from Java code using a typesafe builder pattern, or similar?

Something along the lines of:

```
String sql = DDLGenerator.createTable("MY_TABLE")
                         .withPrimaryKey("my_id").ofNumberType().withPrecision(2, 2)
                         .withColumn("name").ofVarchar2Type().withLength(30).notNull()
                         .withIndexOn("name")
                         .buildSql(Dialect.ORACLE);
```

I'm not looking for an ORM solution such as Hibernate nor a database migration solution such as Liquibase or Flyway, nor a tool that works with an existing schema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## jOOQ

[jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org) provides a [DSL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) for creating tables:

```
Connection conn = ... //code that creates a DB connection
DSLContext create = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.ORACLE);
create.createTable("MY_TABLE")
    .column("my_id", SQLDataType.DECIMAL.precision(2, 2))
    .column("name", SQLDataType.VARCHAR.length(30).nullable(false))
    .withPrimaryKey("my_id").ofNumberType().withPrecision(2, 2)
    .constraints(
        constraint("PK_MY_TABLE").primaryKey("my_id")
    )
    .execute();
create.createIndex("I_MY_TABLE_NAME")
    .on("MY_TABLE", "name")
    .execute();
```

See [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Object_Oriented_Querying).